# python using module and path

Tags: python, path, argv

say I have a module MyModule. MyModule as a function Myfunction. Myfunction does something based on input and pickle file 'my.p' and returns it.

I have a program named MyProgram.py. in MyProgram.py I import MyModule and use Myfunction a lot. like :

```
from MyModule import MyFunction
```

MyProgram.py takes some input files.

MyModule.py and MyProgram.Py and my.p are all in same folder.

Problem is, I wanna launch MyProgram.py on windows explorer. I told you that it takes some input files. So My (in fact the man I'm writing this program for) preferable method is click on the input file, drag and drop onto MyProgram.py, and tada! everything is done.

The bad part is that If I do that that way, It throws an error message, saying it cant find my.p.

if I goto commandline and type

```
>python MyProgram.py input.text
```

there is no problem here.

I think I have to append something to sys.argv but I have no idea really. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is caused by using relative path names.

use absolute paths:

```
from os.path import realpath, dirname
BASE_PATH = dirname(realpath(__file__))
myp       = open(BASE_PATH+'/my.p')
```